# data transfer in vb6

Tags: database, vb6

i have two databases name (trial1) and (trial2)  and table name studmast in trial1 and trial2. I want to transfer data of studmast in trial1 to studmast in trial2. can anybody help me??

Answer (score 2):

Generally:

```
INSERT INTO trial2..studmast SELECT * FROM trial1..studmast
```

Of course, databases can vary quite a bit, so the exact syntax will depend on things like what database product you are using.

Answer (score 0):

What part are you having a problem with? Your question is tagged VB6 - do you know how to access databases using VB6?

If not, you'll probably want to use the ADO library. To do that, add a reference (Project->References) to "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects Library" (choose the earliest version you have on your machine for best compatibility with other systems).

Then you can create a database connection and execute commands using the `ADODB.Connection` and `ADODB.Command` objects.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675104(VS.85).aspx) for examples. (There's too much to repeat here).